# Jquery textbox event which should fire as soon as user stop typing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textbox who has class "payment". This textbox is of number type. Below is HTML code for that:

```
<input type="number" id="payement-textbox" class="payment" min="0" max="100000" step="any" maxlength="9" value="" />
```

My requirement is that, if user enters any number less than 100 then an alert message will come up that you cannot enter an amount less than 100.

But problem is that, as soon as user start typing, it keep generating alert message without letting user write completely.
Below is the code for the same:

```
$(document).on("keyup paste",'input.payment', function(event) {
     var num = parseFloat($(this).val());
    if ( num < 100) {
         alert("you cannot enter an amount less than 100");
    } 
});
```

I learnt about clearTimeout. And I used it this way:

```
 $(document).on("keyup paste",'input.payment', function(event) {
            clearTimeout(typingTimer);
            typingTimer = setTimeout(function(){
             var num = parseFloat($(this).val());
                if ( num < 100) {
                     alert("you cannot enter an amount less than 100");
                } 
        , 3000);
});
```

But its not working. Any idea?

Comment: Why not just set the `min` attribute to `100`...?

Comment: do you mean .change() event?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: For illustration purpose, I wrote the value 100. But actually its not 100. Its a dynamically generated value.

Comment: ... so set the `min` property dynamically too? You can make this much easier than you are

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: You are not understanding. This textbox are part of a table column. These textbox are generated dynamically using loop. Later we need to compare the value which is typed by user by another column of table. Its complicated. Min thing wont work here.

Comment: I'm 99% sure it will, but I can't help with the lack of information you've provided, so I will wish you good luck.

Comment: @Teddu the key question you have to answer is: how you will you know when a user stops typing? That will govern your answer to everything. besides, the below answers offer excellent solutions: (i) blur, (ii) show the error, why not change your design to one of those solutions otherwise it can get very frustrating? Just my 2 cents

Comment: @BKSpurgeon: I can't change design. it is designed by product owner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that the value of `this` needs to be based on the event handler, in that case you can define a variable inside before `setTimeout` as `var self = this`. That way you are getting the correct *"`this`"*. Next define your timer simply a global `var typingTimer` will work (*this way you don't get an undefined error*). Finally you seem to have a typo where you didn't close a brace.

The below code will work as you expect it, when the users stops typing after 3 seconds an alert will pop up if the current value is less than 100:

```js
  var typingTimer;

  $(document).on("keyup paste",'input.payment', function(event) {
      clearTimeout(typingTimer);
      var self = this;
      typingTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        var num = parseFloat($(self).val());
        if ( num < 100) {
          alert("you cannot enter an amount less than 100");
        } 
      }, 3000);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="payement-textbox" class="payment" min="0" max="100000" step="any" maxlength="9" value="" />
```

Comment: @Teddu if you decrease the time 3000 ms to something 1000 or 500 ms. you get alert in real time.

Comment: @Teddu You don't have to put the `parseFloat` inside timeout move it outside and it will work. just take care of the if's closing.

Comment: @Jai Yes I noticed, I mainly did it to point of the scope of `this` is different inside `setTimeout()`. Since your solution already covered it I don't think it's necessary for me to edit it.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek That's fine. But that is quick and nice one.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: But this solution has one limitation, that there are so many textbox like this in a table. I need to sum all the values of these textboxes. So what I am doing:
$(".payment").each(function(){
     if($(this).val() != ""){
      sum = sum + parseFloat($(this).val());
     }
    });

But this gave sum eight times more when I put it inside timeOut function. Any idea?

Comment: @Teddu In that case you probably want a button that calculates the sum of the text elements on click. Or if you want it to be more "real-time" display the sum on the page rather than through an alert.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `change`. It fires as soon as user removes the focus from the checkbox.

```
$(document).on("change",'input.payment', function(event) {
     var num = parseFloat($(this).val());
    if ( num < 100) {
         alert("you cannot enter an amount less than 100");
    } 
});
```

Or, better yet, don't alert but write the error:

```js
$(document).on("keyup paste", 'input.payment', function(event) {
  var num = parseFloat($(this).val());
  if (num < 100) {
    $("#error").text("you cannot enter an amount less than 100")
  } else {
    $("#error").text("")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="payement-textbox" class="payment" min="0" max="100000" step="any" maxlength="9" value="" />
<div id="error" style="color:red"></div>
```

Comment: I have used change event.. but it doesn't fire alert message as soon as user stop typing. User have to click anywhere on the page then it fires

Comment: You have put exactly mine code. Did you read my query? I need to generate only browser alert message. That browser alert should only come up when user will stop typing. Its not happening with change event.

Comment: @Teddu I didn't put exactly your code. Have you read my answer? Why is writing the error a problem?

Comment: Because "alert" message is my requirement. I cant write error. It is not in my hand. Please be specific to the question which has been asked.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me your second try should work but with one change, Instead of `parseFloat()` use `parseInt()` and you have missed the `$(this)` context as that is not the `input.payment` element. Instead you can use `.bind(this)` to run the `setTimeout` in the current selector's context or you can cache it before with a variable and then use that. See it working below:

```js
var typingTimer;
$(document).on("keyup paste", 'input.payment', function(event) {
  clearTimeout(typingTimer);
  typingTimer = setTimeout(function() {
    var num = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    if (num < 100) {
      alert("you cannot enter an amount less than 100");
    }  // <------------You have missed this closing.
  }.bind(this), 3000); // <================see here.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="payement-textbox" class="payment" min="0" max="100000" step="any" maxlength="9" value="" />
```

Or the other solution is to move the variable outside of timout:

```js
var typingTimer;
$(document).on("keyup paste", 'input.payment', function(event) {
  var num = parseFloat($(this).val());
  clearTimeout(typingTimer);
  typingTimer = setTimeout(function() {
    if (num < 100) {
      alert("you cannot enter an amount less than 100");
    } // <-------you have missed this closing.
  }, 3000); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="payement-textbox" class="payment" min="0" max="100000" step="any" maxlength="9" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**blur**](https://api.jquery.com/blur/) event, which will fire as soon as the focus(cursor) is removed from the input

```
$(document).on("blur paste",'input.payment', function(event) {
    // Rest of the code 
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/tyqv8pbx/)

Comment: I have tried blur event already. But it doesnt fire as soon as user stop typing. User have to click somewhere on the page then only it fires

Comment: @Teddu i dont think there is any event which says if user has stopped typing, since the cursor will be still in input box

Answer (score 0):

```
 <html>
   <head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
      var timer; 
var typingInterval = 2000;
var value = $('#payement-textbox')

value.on('keyup', function () {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(abcd, typingInterval);
});

//on keydown, clear the countdown 
value.on('keydown', function () {
  clearTimeout(timer);
});

//user is "finished typing," do something
function abcd () {
    if($('#payement-textbox').val()<100)
  alert('No can not be less than 100');
}
      })
    </script>
   </head>
   <body>
    <input type="number" id="payement-textbox" class="payment" min="0" max="100000" step="any" maxlength="9" value="" />
   <body>
   </html>
```

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eradi_singh/tygerejL/)

Or use underscore.js

```
$('.payment').keyup(_.debounce(abcd , 500));
```

Comment: My condition was "LESS THAN" 100. Edit your JSFiddle code for the same. And then you will see its not working.

Comment: Please Check this entire updated code it will do as your wish was trying to execute the code